# .htaccess rewrite image in cakephp 2.5

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cakephp, cakephp-2.5

According to :

[.htaccess rewrite image file to php script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703862/htaccess-rewrite-image-file-to-php-script)

I am trying to Rewrite an image to an action, in cakephp 2.5. The .htaccess used is the one inside /app/webroot/ according to this post: [Adaptive images CakePHP htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15105877/adaptive-images-cakephp-htaccess)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    RewriteRule ^img/logo.png$ /users/display_details [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

The result displayed is 'missing controller' page, with.

```
<?php
class ImgController extends AppController {

}
```

Any guess to make this working ? Thanks.

Comment: Does the image actually exist? If not, then all you need is to connect a CakePHP route with a matching path.

Comment: @ndm yes the image exists, if I don't set a rule in the .htaccess it display the image. I tried with the cakephp route way but it seems it's not meant to use it in this kind of case (rewrite image to action)

Answer (score 0):

Your rule will not change any of the server variables that CakePHP looks up for matching its routes (`PATH_INFO`, `REQUEST_URI`, `SCRIPT_NAME`, `HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL`), so CakePHP will still see and match on `/img/logo.png`, it will ignore the `REDIRECT_URL` that is being set by your rule, hence it will look for `ImgController`.

You could try to set the `PATH_INFO` variable via the `E` (envelope) flag, like:

```
RewriteRule ^img/logo.png$ index.php [NC,L,E=PATH_INFO:/users/display_details]
```

This should set `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` to `/users/display_details`, and CakePHP should be able to match a route against it.

See also

- **[Apache > HTTP Server > Documentation > Version 2.4 > RewriteRule Flags > E|env](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_e)**

Answer (score 0):

I did not try your solution because I found a way to make it working.

Into the routes.php I added this line

```
Router::connect('/images/logo.png', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'display_details'));
```

It's kind of weird, true but it works. The real image is `/img/logo.png` so inside the display_details , I have a code to display the real image and run some code into this function too.